# How do I load test async response?

Tags: node.js, botframework, load-testing

I am developing a bot application, using LUIS and MS Bot Framework, written in Node.js.

I am trying to load test my bot but the problem is that LUIS response is Async, which means my load test must be able to receive new incoming connection some time after the initial request.

Which framework would be able to handle this?  I looked at the following and none seem to be able to do it:  `JMeter`, `Dimon`, `Artillery`, [Bot Framework Load Testing](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/load-testing-a-bot/).

EDIT:  What about QMetry?  Anyone having experience can comment on its feasibility?

Comment: Hi Bill, have you tried creating a mock response from LUIS? Basically simulate it. In that way you can test your bot for different response time scenarios controlled by a timer that you can set in your code.

Comment: Hi.  If I mock a response, wouldn't that defeat the whole purpose of load testing?  I specifically want to check how long a response is coming back.

Comment: Why do you want to load test the LUIS service? It's a black-box, cloud based service, so even if you benchmark its response times for some sample data right now, you've got no way to know whether performance is going to be better or worse for other data at a different time - you don't know how it handles capacity scaling, etc. It doesn't necessarily make sense to load test a global scale public API, especially one where you may be paying per call.

Comment: Bill, I think Sam has a point here. For your case I would just test your bot forgetting about LUIS. There is no guaranteed average response time and they don't provide any information regarding this. You can assume an average time for external services and count on possible delays depending on a variety of factors